# Как изменить статус товаров, у которого нет изображения на "Черновик"?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Как поменять статус товара с "Опубликовано" на "Черновик", если у товара нет изображения.

Что необходимо прописать в условии?

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_is_visible', function( $visible, $id ) {
if ( ! has_post_thumbnail( $id ) ) {
// change status
}
return $visible;
}, 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вы можете это сделать через функцию  `wp_update_post`

```
if ( ! has_post_thumbnail( $id ) ) { 
    wp_update_post( [
        'ID' =>  $id,
        'post_status' => 'draft'
    ] );
}
```

если нужно исколючить все товары без изображения из запросов на фронте, то нужно использовать экшн `pre_get_posts`

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'products_pre_get_posts' );

function products_pre_get_posts( $query ) {
    if ( ! is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && $query->get( 'post_type' ) == 'product' ) {
        $meta_query = (array) $query->get( 'meta_query' );
        $meta_query[] = [
            'key' => '_thumbnail_id',
            'compare' => 'EXISTS'
        ];
        $query->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );
    }
}
```

Comment: Да, уже использую этот вариант, почти работает, товары пропадают, но только после перехода на нужную пагинацию и обновления страницы. Не знаете, в чем могут быть причины этого?

Comment: может быть из-за того , что сначала идет проверка а потом только обновление постов?

Comment: Это происходит потому что вы делаете это в цикле, вам нужно либо выбрать другой фильтр либо написать запрос который изменит статус товаров без изображений

Comment: а не подскажете тогда какой фильтр выбрать, чтобы это работало корректно?

Comment: просто много информации перекопал, не знаю как правильнее написать запрос, чтобы всё работало корректно.

Comment: сколько у вас товаров?

Comment: около 500 наверно, они добавляются на сайт с мой склад, соответственно нужно чтобы изначально без фото товары не выводились)

Comment: @alexey.orlov94 можно попробовать этот экшн woocommerce_after_product_object_save он в качестве первого аргумента примимает обьект product поэтому id товара вам нужно будет получить учитывая класс wc_product. если этот фильтр не поможет то нужно найти код который обновляет или создает товары ну и соответственно место в котором добавляются изображения и после этого уже принимать решения как сделать товары черновиками если изображения нет

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо, сейчас буду смотреть

Comment: Вот данное решение почти работает, но товар остается все равно на сайте (через поиск можно найти). Может можно как то преобразовать данный код? 
function _additional_woo_query( $query ) {
  $meta_query = $query->get( 'meta_query' ); 
  $meta_query[] = array(
      'key'     => '_thumbnail_id',
      'compare' => 'EXISTS'
    );
  $query->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query ); 
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', '_additional_woo_query' );

Comment: можно вот так сделать add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'products_pre_get_posts' );
function products_pre_get_posts( $query ) {
    if (  ! is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && $query->is_search() ) {
        _additional_woo_query( $query );
    }
}

Comment: Что-то ничего не выходит, может я неправильно весь код пишу, т.к. в wordpress я новичок. А может можно как то в meta query задать product_visibility скрыто?

Comment: не могли бы написать полный код, который должен получится с тем условием, что вы написали выше?

Comment: @alexey.orlov94 изменил ответ

Comment: Спасибо! Практически корректная работа, но во-первых работает только если убрать  "$query->get( 'post_type' ) == 'product'", а во-вторых в сайдбаре, где выводятся категории и количество товара, в количестве всё равно учитывает данный товар.

Comment: но при этом при всем не работает главная страница :/